# Standard solutions to keep LAN connection up

Tags: linux, networking, local-area-network

Do you use some "standard" solution to manage your server connectivity? In particular, how do you ensure that, week after week of uptime, your LAN remains connected, even if the router should reboot or other temporary problem should occur?

Since some years, I've arranged this using a custom script (loaded by `init`) which periodically pings the router, and in case it doesn't reply, a reconnection is attempted.

But I wonder if the norm is to write a custom script like this by yourself, or if there is some standard solution ready to go.

Comment: Use quality server and networking equipment. There shouldn't be a need to write additional scripts for this. What types of problems are you trying to protect against?

Comment: Some years passed since I deployed this script, but I think that, without it, the NIC-to-router connection wasn't guaranteed to restore in case the router rebooted (eg. powerfailure).

Comment: What do you mean by a "reconnection"?

Comment: With "reconnection" I mean `ifup ${iface_name}`.

Comment: @davide: There's no reason you should ever need to do that. I would suggest you troubleshoot to figure out what problem that's working around and then fix it for real.

Comment: A loss of connection may always happen, for a reason or another. In a freshly installed linux with no fancy additional tools or scripts such as this, who guarantees that the connection is restored after it (for any reason) should drop? The kernel itself, or some daemon (such as network-manager)?

Comment: In ever modern *nix and Windows system, the network interfaces automatically reconnect if they're dropped. But a rebooting router will not cause a NIC to drop (unless it's directly connected). The problems your describing are extremely abnormal. As others have said already, you need to fix the real problems, treating symptoms is crazy.

Comment: @davide: It's not clear what you mean by "a loss of connection". If you mean that the router will stop talking to a machine directly connecting to it such that shutting the machine's interface off and back on fixes it, then there's no reason that "may always happen". In fact, it should never happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short: there is no such thing as a "standard solution" to this problem solely because of the fact that it is not a "standard" problem.

With a modern OS and sane network equipment, there is no need to do anything to ensure the network connection stays up, nor should any "custom script" be required to bring things up after a power outage or other unexpected disconnection.

If you are finding that connections are not being re-established after an unexpected disconnection, then you need to do further troubleshooting to determine the source of the issue.

As an aside, you ought to have some sort of external monitoring in place to detect and alert on events like this.